How to refresh syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2022?

I expect that MoveDirection will be highlighted in lime color, like all other Enum types. It also happening with random types in project. What steps should I take to refresh syntax highlighting in IDE?
The only thing that solves the problem is a restart IDE, but not always.
Update: Invoking an rename operation (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) and cancelling it also can be solution.

Just checking: You have the latest version of Visual Studio? (17.10.5). One thing to try is to delete all the temp folders (/bin, /obj, /.vs)

... actually not, only 17.10.3. Maybe that's the problem

Same issue in 17.10.5. You'll need to open a file that contains MoveDirection enum, close the current source file and open it again. It's a temporary remedy for the issue. This bug existed for a few months I think.
